# Can I write it in English: 'I'm praying to God for him to do it'?

Tags: grammar, sentence, phrase-usage

I wanna say that I want something, that God can give me, e.g wings to fly. Can I say:

> I'm praying to God for him to give me wings to fly.

Or should I just say?

> I'm praying to God to give me wings to fly.

Comment: Yes, both those sound fine. 'for him' is a little redundant in the first one but is grammatical and makes sense. As to 'should', some people prefer shorter sentences if nothing is lost.

Comment: Both are fine.  Yes, some will want succinctness, but including "for him" (or "for Him") personalizes it more, and in the context of your sentence, it's actually quite common for people to add the "for him."

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very odd to use "for him" in a sentence like this, referring to God. So you could say your second option, but to be honest it's more natural to shorten it down to:

> I'm praying to God for wings to fly (or "for wings so I can fly")

When I read your original title, which was worded differently, I was going to say yes because that 'him' would naturally refer to a person you want to do something. But if it's referring back to God it just sounds confusing. The extra words are not necessary.

Generally, you pray to God for a thing to happen or for 'something' (to be given to you). So "for him to..." is that something happening, and wouldn't refer back to God but to some other agent (a person).

Comment: Also one more thing - if you ever did want to use 'him' or 'he' in a sentence, referring to God, this is a rare case where the 'H' needs to be capitalised. So, you would say "I pray to God because He is kind". I'm not actually religious, but I would still follow this policy.